# Java HTTP getResponseCode returns 200 for non-existent URL

Tags: java, networking

I was expecting this code to return a 404, however it produces the output :

"Response code is 200"

Would it be possible to learn how to differentiate between existent and non-existent web pages . . . thanks so much,

```
    try
    {
    // create the HttpURLConnection
    URL url = new URL("http://www.thisurldoesnotexist");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    System.out.println("Response code is " + connection.getResponseCode());
    }
```

Comment: If you got a 200 back, then the page *does* exist...

Comment: try `http://www.fackurl.com` and see what you get
probably you'll get exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I see you've call `openConnection()` but not `connect()` - could that be the problem? I would *expect* `getResponseCode()` to actually make the request if it hasn't already, but it's worth just trying that...

---

That suggests you've possible got some DNS resolver which redirects to a "helper" (spam) page, or something like that.

The easiest way to see exactly what's going on here is to use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) - have that up and capturing traffic (HTTP-only, to make life easier) and then run your code. You should be able to see what's going on that way.

Note that I wouldn't have expected a 404 - because that would involve being able to find a web server to talk to to start with. If you're trying to go to a host which doesn't involve, there shouldn't be an HTTP response *at all*. I'd expect `connect()` to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a "connection.connect();" or look at the contents returned...

it could be a dns issue, ie: your dns is being sent to a parking place... for example: freedns does this.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Resolve the IP from the host of the page
2. Try to connect to port 80 on the resolved IP using plain sockets

This is a bit low level however and will add complexity since you will need to make a simple GET request through the socket. Then validate the response so you're sure that its actually a HTTP server running on port 80.

[NMap](http://nmap.org/) might be able to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Like @spgennard - I think this is most likely a DNS issue.

- The URL you have chosen is owned by a DNS speculator.
- The URL you have chosen is "parked" by a DNS provider.
- Your ISP is messing with your DNS results to send your browser to some search page.

It is also possible that you are accessing the web via a proxy, and the proxy is doing something strange.

The way to diagnose this is to look at the other information in the HTTP responses you are getting, particularly the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be getting this error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.thisurldoesnotexist
```

But it looks like your URL is resolved by you DNS provider.

For instance on my company's network running your code with URI "http://profile/" displays
the employee profile.

Please also check etc.home file if you are on windows to check if any settings have been changed.