# How to test if Android HttpURLConnection is valid?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

My app regularly downloads files from a server using `HttpUrlConnection()`. Brief code example below:

```
HttpURLConnection conn;
url = new URL( "http://google.com/index.html" );
conn = url.openConnection();         // returns non-null
int rcode = conn.getResponseCode():  // returns 200
// get input stream, read from it and process bytes read
```

This works just fine. But if I substitute a bogus URL, e.g.

```
url=new URL("http://BOGUS-SITE.com/index.html";
```

it still connects just fine, and getResponseCode() returns response code 200. The input stream reader returns -1 bytes read. OK, so be it.  (Interestingly, if the filename part of the URL is bogus, I *do* get a File-Not-Found exception).

But how can I detect a bad connection (e.g., to non-existent host) before I actually try to read it? Maybe that's not possible?

I suppose I could parse the URL and try to resolve the site name or ping it, but that seems like a hack.

More complete code excerpt:

```
// Download a file by its URL
    public static int
    doDownload(
      String fileurl)   // file url, e.g. "http:google.com/index.html"
    {
        // NOTE: 'log()' is a wrapper for 'Log.i()'
        int BUFSIZE=10000;
        HttpURLConnection hconn;
        int rcode,nr,nrtot=0;
        InputStream is;
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        byte[] buf;
        URL url;

        try {
            url = new URL( fileurl );                       // form URL
            hconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();    // open connection
            log( "Opened connection to \""+fileurl+"\"" );
            rcode = hconn.getResponseCode();                   // get response code
            log("Read HTTP response code: " + rcode);
            is  = hconn.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream( is );                // get buffered stream to read
            buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            while( true ) {                                     // read loop
             nr = bis.read( buf, 0, BUFSIZE );             // read some bytes
             if( nr <= 0 ) break;                              // break read loop on EOF
             nrtot += nr;                                      // update total read count
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
          return( -1 );                                         // rtn ERROR
        }
        return( nrtot );                                        // return num bytes read
    }
```

### Update

I have done some further investigation. I found why sometimes response code 200 is returned and sometimes UnknownHostException occurs: It depends on the particular "bad" url host specified. For example if I specify

- "http://google.com/index.html", code 200 is returned and the download succeeds.
- If I specify ""http://google.comXXX/index.html", 200 is still returned but the download fails (no bytes read). In this case, a different IP address is reported, which nslookup reports as belonging to "akamaitechnologies.com" (???).
- In other cases, UnknownHostException occurs.

I'm now trying other "bad" URLs to try to see a pattern.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes it is in Android Java.

Comment: You are catching the exception `catch( Exception e )`, but throwing it away `return( -1 ); `. Instead, print the stack trace of the exception: `e.printStackTrace(System.err);`. When I do that with your code, I get `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

Comment: @AndrewJames: Yes, but the caller of doDownload reports the error to LogCat if return of -1, and I don't see that.

Comment: When I take the code shown in the question, and run it in IntelliJ (Community Edition) with a bogus site as the example, my code hits the `catch(Exception e )` line, and then returns `-1` to the calling method, as expected. I cannot recreate your results where you get a `200` response from a bogus site. (I am not running in an Android emulator - I see you added "android" as a tag in this new version of the question.)

Comment: I'm confused - I do indeed still see the 200 response code. I also added a log() call before returning -1 but nothing is output so I really don't think any exception is triggered. BTW - I am running on a live device, not an emulator.

Comment: That suggests maybe the problem lies elsewhere, and not in the sample code. Or in how the sample code is interacting with something Android-related not shown in the question. Non-existent domain names cannot return `HTTP 200` response codes - or _any_ response code at all. Sorry I can't help further - but I have no way to recreate the problem.

Comment: I investigated further and found some very bizarre behavior. See updated question for details.

Comment: Well, that sounds more like your request got blocked for having `XXX` in the host name, or something like that... On the plus side, that is a much more specific issue - and you can research that. Or ask a new question (maybe).

Comment: @andrewjames: It appears that my phone is using the DNS of my AT&T Wifi gateway which is using "sbcglobal.net". I don't know where that came from, but I think that's the puppy giving me an IP *even for a bad host*, hence the response code of 200. I'm struggling to change that now.

Comment: I changed the DNS to dns.google (8.8.8.8) and everything is peachy now. See my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java HTTP getResponseCode returns 200 for non-existent URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211251/java-http-getresponsecode-returns-200-for-non-existent-url)

Comment: Helpful note: where you have a post and don't agree with a closure, [you can appeal on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) and ask for a second opinion. It's worth noting that most closures are correct though - people who close-vote tend to have expertise in the tags of the questions they are closing. As long as reopen-seekers are persistent and patient, they will generally succeed - it just takes a bit of effort.

Comment: Given that the resolution is an unusual one, my guess would be that reopening [the older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861846/how-to-test-if-httpurlconnection-is-valid) here might be difficult. Thus in this case I've helped to delete the other one, leaving this question in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a DNS issue. I discovered my AT&T phone was using DNS service by "sbcglobal.net" (AT&T's default DNS server). That DNS server returns an IP address even for a **non-existent** name. In particular, it returns an address belonging to "akamaitechnologies.com" (whatever that is). Since that *is an existing site*, http connects and getResponseCode returns 200. Since it cannot serve my requested file, the download fails. I think this is a marketing gimmick to generate traffic for akamaitechnologies.

**When I set my phone to use a DNS of "dns.google" (8.8.8.8), everything works as expected.**

This type of DNS spoofing is a Bad Thing because many apps depend on an Unknown-Host-Exception to detect an incorrectly entered domain name, e.g. in an email address.

Comment: [Akamai Technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) is a content delivery platform company. I doubt you were seeing a "marketing gimmick" - where you see this domain on the internet, it is likely to be legitimate.

Comment: I stand by my statement that this IS a "marketing gimmick". It is an attempt to direct traffic to Akamai.

Comment: Well, alright - was there marketing material at the address you saw? The address `https://akamaitechnologies.com` resolves to `127.0.0.53` for me in DNS, which I would guess is a local address.